# python logging as JSON

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have spent the last couple of days trying to get python to log in JSON format. I have found some snippets of information on the internet, but yet none of them worked.

The current error message that I am getting doesn't make sense, at least not to me, and I've not managed to find anything on the internet to explain.

> Error: Unable to configure formatter 'json' is the error

```json
"formatters": {
               "simple": {
                          "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s- %(message)s" 
                } ,
                "json": {
                         "fields" : {"level_name": "levelname",
                         "thread_name": "threadName",
                         "process_name": "processName"},
                         "class" : "logging_json.JsonFormatter"
```

```py
import logging.config

gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger("gunicorn.error")
log.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
log.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)

try:
    with open("./config/config.json") as config_file:
        config = json.load(config_file)
```

I have tried with and without fields.  With and without "class" switching `with()` - as that has been suggested.

I have inherited the code, which works writing standard ASCII to a file, but I need to switch to JSON to allow elastic to read the contents.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: The text is all that I get.  Which I am finding of little use!